# IIS 6/MVC 3 Cannot Attach to Process as not listed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

My problem is when I run my MVC 3 app and try to attach to the w3wp process it is not listed in my available processes window and I'm completely stumped as to why not.

I've done everything as mentioned in Phil Haacks article. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx - In IIS application configuration I've added aspnet_isapi as a wildcard application map. The views are .cshtml which weren't showing on the available extensions list so I added that but still no joy finding to process to attach to.

Has anyone experienced similar before and found the cause?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're viewing all processes running under all users? Typically W3WP isn't running under your user account, but NETWORK SERVICE or SYSTEM instead.

Comment: Hi Mastermax, thanks, i just second checked there to make sure it's not something silly like that and am I listing everything and attached to the correct IIS qualifier. There are Network Services being listed but none for my application.